# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10,) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import os
import json
import datetime
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

import tflearn
import tensorflow as tf 

data = pd.read_csv("line.csv")

data.columns = ['total', 'saved', 'lines' , 'inv']
target = list(data['saved'])


#function filter out the columns we wont be using to train the machine 
def preprocess(data, columns_to_ignore):
    data = data.drop(columns=columns_to_ignore)
    return data 

ignore = ['saved' , 'inv']

data = preprocess(data, ignore)

train = [list(l) for l in zip(data['total'], data['lines'])]

# Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 2])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 16)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 16)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Training Neural Network
model = tflearn.DNN(net)

# Start Training using tensorflow gradient descent algorithim 
model = model.fit(train, target, n_epoch=10, batch_size=10, show_metric=True)
```

I keep running into this error. I thought the shape should be:  None , 2 since there are 2 features in the program. The csv file has 4 features. One of them gets filtered out. One is read as the target. What should I do to get rid of this error?

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10,) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'

Answer (score 0):

If I change the labels from 1-D to 2-D I don't see that error.

```
target = list(data['y'])
a = np.array(target)
target = np.reshape(a , (-1,1))
```